# Dynamically bind to Google tagging attribute data-tracking-label=""

Tags: angular5, google-tag-manager

I am trying to bind *data-tracking-label="plan.priceplan_name"*.

Not sure how do i go about binding the priceplan_name dynamically to the data-tracking-label.

Already tried a few options including:
data-tracking-label={{plan.priceplan_name}} - which has error : 
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'tracking-label' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
    <div *ngFor="let plan of plans; let i = index" class="col-md-3 pt-2 pb-2 pl-2 pr-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body row p-0" (click)="selectPlan(plan, i)" data-tracking-category="SEA - Choose-plan" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-label={{plan.priceplan_name}}>
          <div class="first-sec col-6 pt-2 pb-2 rounded-left">
            <h3>{{plan.priceplan_name}}</h3>
            <div class="position-bottom">
              <h2 class="mb-0">R{{plan.base_priceplan_cost | number:'1.0-2'}}pm</h2>
              <h5>x{{plan.contract_duration}}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to add the tags which is being used.

Note that a service with a windowRef provider was added to the app.module.ts and imported in every controller that makes use of the dataLayer.

`(click)="myFunstion(param); dataLayer.push({event:'MyEvent', category:'MyCategory', action:'Click', label:plan.priceplan_name})`

And in the controller:

```
import { WindowRef } from '../WindowRef';
```

Declare var before constructor:

```
dataLayer = this.winRef.nativeWindow.dataLayer;
```

And add variable inside constructor:

```
 private winRef: WindowRef
```